# How to work with 2 RDBMS in a project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sqlite

I'm working with an java-web using MySQL RDBMS and I'm using Hibernate as an ORM in my project. 
Now I upgrade my app to work both on web and on Android, so I'm tending to use SQLite to manipulate data on Android. 
I found the jars to make Hibernate work with SQLite but I cant find out how to make my class use the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src.android.dao` package instead of the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src` package.
If I don't misunderstand something in Hibernate document, they say that *you can work with multi RDBMS at one project*. Then, please tell me how to do it.
My English is bad, so, if I misunderstood, then please confirm that for me (Hibernate cant work with 2 RDBMS in one project) . 
Many thanks!

Comment: You're using Hibernate in Android? How did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "src" really is part of the package, this should work:

```
URL config = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/src/android/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.configure(config);
```

You can have multiple different hibernate configuration files in a project. What they probably meant by supporting multiple databases in the same project is the ability to target them for support, rather than using them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you would need to do:

```
configuration.configure("/android/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Instead of:

```
configuration.configure();
```